# How can i update name in plist?

Tags: iphone, plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>accounts</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>OLDNAME</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

This is The plist File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe It will be too obviously but you can use following ways to modify it:

1. Go into TextEdit and modify content between
2. In an Xcode double-click to plist file and edit it with plist editor that provides a more user friendly UI for editing plist.
3. Write an ObjectiveC code with use of NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver classes to load, modify and save dictionary.

Ultimate solution for manipulating dictionaries stored in plists:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@ "plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
[plistDictionary setValue:@"newName" forKey:@"testKey"];
[plistDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Hope you will adopt this code sample for your own needs.

... Ok, I got it here is a code sample for your particular plist structure:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPlist" ofType:@ "plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *accountsArray = [(NSArray *)[plistDictionary valueForKey:@"accounts"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *accountDictionary = [(NSDictionary *)[accountsArray objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];

[accountDictionary setValue:@"NewName" forKey:@"name"];
[accountsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:accountDictionary];
[plistDictionary setValue:accountsArray forKey:@"accounts"];

[plistDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Follow the third proposed way. It is usually pretty easy to implement. It is very high-level classes to work with plists.

Comment: can u show me a tutorial for NSKeyedArchiver in update plist file?

Comment: Give me several minutes, I will post a code sample into my answer.

Comment: Added a code sample. Just during writing a code piece remembered a better way that applicable to your case. :) I hope it will work.

Comment: i know this method but i want to change OLDNAME in 2nd DICT!?

Comment: Load your dictionary and follow the structure of it. So you have a dictionary where in key "accounts" array is stored. And in array object with index 0 is your dictionary with name. Where name key contains your OLDNAME.

Comment: What type of an error? This information is not enough to help you.

Comment: i can't set value do you know why?

Comment: You are right. It is my fault. A dictionary is not mutable. What you need to do is to get a mutable copies of all the dictionaries that you want to modify and modify them one by one and save result. Is such explanation clear?

Comment: i more question how can i add new NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary ?

Comment: just choose a new key and use the same call setValue:forKey:

Answer (score 0):

Apple has plenty of docs on the topic.

Here is one that should help:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/CFPropertyLists.html

Comment: The [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) is probably better for beginners. Manipulating property lists with Core Foundation is needlessly complicated if you can have the easier Cocoa API.